# Enable shortcut keys on outlook form region

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin

I am creating addin for outlook. I am using outlook form region of vsto as adjoining. The issue is in my outlook form region shortcut keys are not working. I need to work tabs and enter keys on my controls. Any help will be appreciated.